# Proving $2^n\leq 2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1$ for all $n\geq 1$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I am trying to prove that for every element of $\mathbb{N}$, that
                   $2^n \leq 2^{n+1} - 2^{n-1} - 1.$
I started by showing that initial case, of $n=1$, is true. Then I proceed to the inductive step by assuming that for some $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$, 
                   $2^k \leq 2^{k+1} - 2^{k-1} - 1$. 
Then, for $n=k+1$,
                   $2^{k+1} \leq 2^{k+2} - 2^{k} - 1$.
Is this sufficient to prove the statement by induction or do I have to expand the exponentials to rearrange the inequality in a different way?

Comment: I think you should improve a little bit readability (no offense intended) if you want to gain attention.

Comment: @DanielEscudero, I second that.

Comment: As BirdKiller1989 pointed out, what you have so far is not enough. You have to **earn** (i.e., *show*) that $2^{k+1}\leq 2^{k+2}-2^k-1$ follows from the inductive assumption.  My answer was meant to provide you with a way of seeing how to get that inequality by actually using the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the meat of the inductive proof:
\begin{align}
2^{k+1} &= 2\cdot 2^{k}\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&\leq 2\cdot(2^{k+1}-2^{k-1}-1)\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
&= 2^{k+2}-2^k-2\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&\leq 2^{k+2}-2^k-1.
\end{align}
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k\leq 2(2^{k+1}-2^{k-1}-1)$$

and use the inequality $k\lt k+1~\forall~k\in\Bbb{R}$

Can you continue?

Comment: It'd have been better if the equality wasn't there in the statement to be proved since equality doesn't occur for the inductive step (as far as I can see).

Comment: What do you mean by "equality doesn't occur for the inductive step"?  $<$ is stronger than $\leq$ so it really doesn't matter to use $\leq$, but it does seem unnecessary. Also, is there a reason you are using $\{\quad\}$ instead of $(\quad)$ in your inequality?

Comment: @crash, nope, there is no reason for using the parenthesis. And by "equality doesn't occur", I mean that we cannot have the equality case since equality doesn't hold for any $k$ as LHS and RHS always will have a difference of $1~\forall~k$. But we needn't worry about all that since it doesn't affect this proof.

Comment: I just changed the braces to parens; hope you don't mind--it seems much more standard. Feel free to rollback if you have a problem with it.

Comment: @crash, I don't have any problem with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not sufficient. You've only proved that it's true for $n=1$ and assumed the claim is true for $n=k$. Those two itself are not enough to automatically say $n=k+1$: you have to use the assumption from $n=k$ to build and prove that the claim is also true for $n=k+1$.